# Is this design a good way to access a web service in MVC fashion?

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, design-patterns, rest, asihttprequest

EDIT: My ultimate goal is to totally decouple `ASIHTTPRequest` and `ModelListingViewController`, so that I can do `self.modelArray = [Model arrayOfModelWithDelegate:self]` and perhaps implement a few of my own callbacks rather than the ASI ones.

I've crafted several iPhone apps that utilize a RESTful service and ASIHTTPRequest. I've never been happy with how they are designed as I always feel the parsing, model, and view controller classes are tightly coupled. For my next app update, I'd like to use this design for web service access:

```
ModelListingViewController --- self ---> Model +(NSArray*)arrayOfModelWithDelegate:MLVC

+(NSArray*)arrayOfModelWithDelegate ---> ModelWSController:WSController +(NSArray*)getAllModel
```

in `WSController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ASIHTTPRequest *request;
...
- (void)performRequest {
   //global request stuff, like authentication, headers, etc
   [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

in `ModelWSController`:

```
- (NSArray *)getAllModelWithDelegate:(id)delegate {
    request.url = @"Appropriate URL"; //or could use a more sophisticated internal url routing system defined by model class name
    request.delegate = delegate;
    [ModelWSController performRequest];
}
```

and in the `ModelListingViewController`:

`self.arrayOfModel = [Model arrayOfModelWithDelegate:self];`

Something seems wrong with this design, particularly in how `ModelWSController` and `WSController` are interfaced, but I do not know what. Specifically, the passing along of `delegate` two times down the chain seems bizarre.

Input is appreciated and I would like to know how you have designed using MVC principles for accessing a RESTful web service. Also, please let me know if blocks would be a better way to handle this.

Comment: lets try and get this question answered. I cant say fully what is wrong. But from your post Ive taken that your model is local, but is also remote (restful service). Is this correct?

You also talk of multiple controllers?

Answer (score 1):

The architecture for .NET applications can probably be applied here. Typically you add an application services layer between your service calls and the controller. It is similar to a command/executor pattern, where the responsibility of the application services tier is to implement an interface to the external services.

A good example would be trying to write a generic weather service that can consume from both google and yahoo weather. Your goal should be to implement both services to a common contract where a simple configuration change switches google weather to yahoo weather. Your app is dependent on the interface and not the actual implementation.

Dependency injection frameworks for iOS like [Objection](http://objection-framework.org/) help with making that configuration change a very small one.